# How to get IMDb's serie release year and end year?

Tags: php, regex, numbers, extract, imdb

I've been trying to get out some info from IMDb serie page, including the following data:

- Name
- **Release year\End Year (if exists)**
- Rating
- Seasons (number)
- Duration

It seems like the page include the Release year\End Year in 3 different options:

1. *If the serie is still running*: **(2018-)**
2. *If serie had only 1 year*: **(2018)**
3. *If serie ended after a few years*: **(2017-2018)**

An example html code:

```
<title>Collateral (TV Mini-Series 2018) - IMDb</title>
```

My code so far:

```
         if(isset($_GET['imdb'])) {
                if(isset($_POST['btnGetContent'])) {
                    $cUrl = curl_init(); 
                    curl_setopt($cUrl,CURLOPT_URL, "{$_POST['getContentUrl']}");
                    curl_setopt($cUrl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
                    curl_setopt($cUrl,CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 
                    $output = curl_exec($cUrl);
                    curl_close($cUrl);
                    $array = array();
                    if(preg_match('/<h1 itemprop="name"[^>]*>(.*?)\s+g*<\/h1>/',$output,$matches)) {
                        $array["title"] = htmlspecialchars(str_replace("&nbsp;","",$matches[1]));
                    }
                    if(preg_match('/TV Series \((\d{4})(?-:.*)\)/',$output,$matches)) {
                        $array["releaseYear"] = $matches[1];
                    }
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Just FYI, [TMDB](https://www.themoviedb.org/) has an API. Might be worth looking into, if you are not limited to IMDB.

Comment: @IcedAnt Thank you, but unfortunately I am limited to IMDb. It also doesn't seem to include the end-year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
                        if(preg_match('/<title>.*?\((.*?)\).*?IMDb<\/title>/',$output,$matches)) {
                        //(YYYY-YYYY)
                        if(preg_match('/.*?(\d{4}).*?(\d{4})/',$matches[1],$match)) {
                            $array["releaseYear"] = $match[1];
                            $array["endYear"] = $match[2];
                        }
                        // (YYYY- )
                        else if(preg_match('/.*?(\d{4})./',$matches[1],$match)) {
                            $array["releaseYear"] = $match[1];
                            $array["endYear"] = "0";
                        }
                        // (YYYY)
                        else if(preg_match('/.*?(\d{4})/',$matches[1],$match)) {
                            $array["releaseYear"] = $match[1];
                            $array["endYear"] = $match[1];
                        }
                    }
```